# ios 7.1 simulator doesn't download in xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator, osx-yosemite

I have Xcode 6.1.1 and I want to run my app in deployment target : iOS 7.0 , so I tried to download the iOS 7.1 Simulator, but **the progress bar is still white (no progress)[image]**

**How do I fix this problem? and is there an another way to download this simulator?** When I put deployment target : ios 7.0 the default simulator doesn't run , it is run only in deployment target : ios 8.0. **Note** : I am using Swift if it has any affect and my Mac OS version is : **OS X Yosemite 10.10.1**

Comment: I am having the same issue in Xcode 6.1.1, Yosemite 10.10.1. I am working with an Objective-C project, so I don't think Swift is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a laptop? I was having this issue while trying to download anything from Xcode. The actual culprit turned out to be **my laptop not being plugged in**. Apple products seem to halt all downloads on battery power. For some reason Xcode doesn't show any message whereas the App Store immediately complains. I plugged in my laptop and it immediately started downloading.

Comment: Finally :D thx bro : ). Strange issue from a big name "Apple"!

Answer (score 1):

Potential Solution:

I started the download on 6.0.1, had the same kind of problem. The download progress bar never showed any progress, but I noticed in system activity that data was coming in. I waited until I could see over 900 Mbytes was received (the download is only 850 or so).

I double clicked the entry (near the progress bar) and got a message that an error had occurred - try again later. I closed and re-opened XCode, and the install HAD completed.

6.1.1 on Mavericks did the same thing, but 6.1.1 on Yosemite worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by reinstalling Xcode 6.1.1. I trashed the existing app in `/Applications` and redownloaded it from the App Store. I then went to reinstall the 7.1 simulator and it worked (though it was slow).

I should also say that the iOS 7.0 Simulator is not available on Yosemite. Only 7.1 and 8.1.

Comment: I did the same but still no download progress :/:/. any another solution plz ?

Answer (score 0):

## More than 1 Xcode?

I was able to replicate this by having **both** an `Xcode` and `Xcode-beta` installed concurrently.

Downloading legacy simulator did not work on `Xcode`, but did succeed on the `Xcode-beta`. Restarting (or rebooting) `Xcode` surprisingly worked, and the legacy simulator is available from *both* Xcode versions.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, progress did not move but data was .
To see progress I contracted and then expanded "components" tab. And after expanding I saw real progress